# What's the difference between groupingby and mapping in Collectors (Java)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Take a look at this piece of code.

```
// group by price, uses 'mapping' to convert List<Item> to Set<String>
    Map<BigDecimal, Set<String>> result =
            items.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice,
                            Collectors.mapping(Item::getName, Collectors.toSet())
                    )
            );
```

Is groupingBy and Mapping interchangeable? What is their differences?

For the third parameter in collect(), would I get the same output type Map if I used Collectors.toList() instead  of Collectors.toSet()? I heard that toList() is a more popular option.

Comment: `toList()` is “more popular” in that it is the default when no additional collector has been specified, i.e. `Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice)` has the same outcome has `Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice, Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45231351/32453

Answer (score 25):

No, the two are completely different.

`Collectors.groupingBy` takes a function which creates keys and returns a collector which returns a map from keys to collections of objects in the stream which have that same key.

`Collectors.mapping`, on the other hand, takes a function and another collector, and creates a new collector which first applies the function and then collects the mapped elements using the given collectors. Thus, the following are equivalent:

```
items.stream().map(f).collect(c);
items.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(f, c));
```

`Collectors.mapping` is most useful in situations where you do not have a stream, but you need to pass a collector directly. An example of such a situation is when using `Collectors.groupingBy`.

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice, Collectors.toSet()))
```

yields a `Map<BigDecimal,Set<Item>>` (assuming `getPrice()` returns a `BigDecimal`). However,

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice,
    Collectors.mapping(Item::getName, Collectors.toSet())))
```

returns a `Map<BigDecimal,Set<String>>`. Before collecting the items, it first applies `Item.getName` to them.

Answer (score 20):

> Is groupingBy and Mapping interchangeable?

No, they are completely different. `groupingBy` lets you create a `Map` where the key is the first argument passed to `groupingBy` and the value is a `List` of the element type of the `Stream`.

`Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getPrice)` would generate a `Map<BigDecimal, List<Item>>` (assuming `Item::getPrice` returns a `BigDecimal`. Passing the `mapping` `Collector` as an argument to `Collectors.groupingBy()` allows you to change the value of the output map (in your example, you change it to `Set<String>`).

> For the third parameter in collect(), would I get the same output type Map if I used Collectors.toList() instead of Collectors.toSet()?

No, you would get a `Map<BigDecimal, List<String>>`.

Comment: I couldn't format this sorry!! If grouping by creates a map, then whats the difference between groupingby and Collectors.toMap() or Collectors.Map()?           Map<String, EmailAddress> mapAliasAddress =
        Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                .map(s -> s.split(","))
                .map(sArr -> new EmailAddress(sArr[1], sArr[0]))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        email -> email.getAlias(),
                        email -> email
                ));

Comment: @NoMoreErrors `Collectors.toMap` creates a `Map` without grouping, i.e. each element of the input Stream is mapped to an Entry of the output Map (assuming there are no duplicate keys). `groupingBy` maps multiple elements of the input Stream that share some property into a single Entry of the output Map.

Comment: So am I right to say that Collectors.toMap and Collectors.Mapping is exactly the same?

Comment: I'm referring to toMap

Comment: @NoMoreErrors No, `Collectors.mapping()` cannot produce a `Map` (unless it is used in combination with `groupingBy`). For example, if you have a `List<String>`, you can produce a `Set<Integer>` with `Set<Integer> lengths = list.stream ().collect(Collectors.mapping (s->s.length (),Collectors.toSet()));`, but not a `Map`.