# Differences between Collectors.toMap() and Collectors.groupingBy() to collect into a Map

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

I want to create a `Map` from a `List` of `Points` and have inside the map all entries from the list mapped with the same parentId such as `Map<Long, List<Point>>`.
I used `Collectors.toMap()` but  it doesn't compile :

```
Map<Long, List<Point>> pointByParentId = chargePoints.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Point::getParentId, c -> c));
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Comment: I agree with LouisWasserman 's  interpretation of the question, but you should be more clear in your question. Provide some example input and output , or even a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**TLDR :**

To collect into a `Map` that contains a single value by key (`Map<MyKey,MyObject>`), use [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).
To collect into a `Map` that contains multiple values by key (`Map<MyKey, List<MyObject>>`), use [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

---

**Collectors.toMap()**

By writing :

```
chargePoints.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Point::getParentId, c -> c));
```

The returned object will have the `Map<Long,Point>` type.
Look at the `Collectors.toMap()` function that you are using :

```
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper)
```

It returns a `Collector` with as result `Map<K,U>` where `K` and `U` are the type of return of the two functions passed to the method.
In your case, `Point::getParentId` is a Long and `c` refers to a `Point`.
Whereas the  `Map<Long,Point>` returned when `collect()` is applied on.

And this behavior is rather expected as [Collectors.toMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) javadoc states :

> returns a `Collector` that accumulates elements into a `Map` whose keys and values
>   are the result of applying the provided mapping functions to the input
>   elements.

But if the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException` is thrown
It will be probably  your case as you will group the `Point`s according to a specific property : `parentId`.

If the mapped keys may have duplicates, you could use the [`toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) overload but it will not really solve your problem as it will not group elements with the same `parentId`. It will just provide a way to not have two elements with the same `parentId`.

---

**Collectors.groupingBy()**

To achieve your requirement, you should use [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) which the behavior and the method declaration suits much better to your need :

```
public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>>
groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier)
```

It is specified as :

> Returns a Collector implementing a "group by" operation on input
>   elements of type T, grouping elements according to a classification
>   function, and returning the results in a Map.

The method takes a `Function`.
In your case, the `Function` parameter is `Point` (the `type` of Stream) and you  return `Point.getParentId()` as you want to group elements by `parentId` values.

So you could write :

```
Map<Long, List<Point>> pointByParentId = 
                       chargePoints.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( p -> p.getParentId()));
```

Or with a method reference :

```
Map<Long, List<Point>> pointByParentId = 
                       chargePoints.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getParentId));
```

---

**Collectors.groupingBy() : go further**

Indeed the `groupingBy()` collector goes further than the actual example. 
The `Collectors.groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier)` method is finally just a convenient method to store the values of the collected `Map` in a `List`.
To store values of the `Map` in another thing than a `List` or to store the result of a specific computation , `groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,                                          Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)` should interest you.

For example :

```
Map<Long, Set<Point>> pointByParentId = 
                       chargePoints.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getParentId, toSet()));
```

So beyond the asked question, you should consider `groupingBy()` as a flexible way to choose values that you want to store into the collected `Map`, what definitively `toMap()` is not.

Comment: @TimSchwalbe on [so] instead of saying thanks we upvote and accept answers.

Comment: Looking around for information on toMap()! Saying hello!

Answer (score 4):

`Collectors.groupingBy` is exactly what you want, it creates a Map from your input collection, creating an Entry using the `Function` you provide for it's key, and a List of Points with your associated key as it's value.

```
Map<Long, List<Point>> pointByParentId = chargePoints.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getParentId));
```

Comment: documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 4):

The following code does the stuff. `Collectors.toList()` is the default one, so you can skip it, but in case you want to have `Map<Long, Set<Point>>` `Collectors.toSet()` would be needed.

```
Map<Long, List<Point>> map = pointList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getParentId, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite often true that a map from object.field to Collection of objects that share this field is better stored in a Multimap (Guava has a nice implementation for a multimap).
If you don't NEED the multimap to be mutable (which should be the desired case), you can use

```
Multimaps.index(chargePoints, Point::getParentId);
```

If you must use a mutable map, you can either implement a collector (as demonstrated here: https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/29/java-8-collector-for-gauvas-linkedhashmultimap/) or use a for loop (or forEach) to populate an empty, mutable multimap.

A multimap gives you additional functionality that you normally need when you use a map from field to collection of objects sharing a field (like the count of total objects).

A mutable multimap also makes it easier to add and remove elements to the map (without being concerned with the edge cases).