# Java 8 Collectors.toMap with ArrayList as value

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert given 2d array to map using java 8.
Input - { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 } }
The output should be of form
Map<Integer, List> map = new HashMap<>();
Output - {1=[0], 2=[0], 3=[1, 2]}

Below is my solution

```
for (int[] prereq : prerequisites) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(prereq[0], k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(prereq[1]);
        }
```

Any better approach, if for loop can be replaced with streams.

Comment: Your approach looks fine. If you are on java 9+ and you don't plan to change the list, in such case you can do the following change  `map.computeIfAbsent(prereq[0], k -> List.of(prereq[1]);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To collect into a Map that contains multiple values by key use `Collectors.groupingBy`.

```
int[][] prerequisites = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}};
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> res = Arrays.stream(prerequisites).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x[0], Collectors.mapping(x -> x[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Output:

```
{1=[0], 2=[0], 3=[1, 2]}
```

Comment: Map<Integer, List<Integer>> res = Arrays.stream(prerequisites).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(x -> x[0], x -> Arrays.asList(x[1]), (x1, x2) -> Arrays.asList(x1.get(0), x2.get(0))));

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Acutually groupingBy is better choice when map key has multiple value, toMap used generally for single value map and when you want merge function by own. Read more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231351/differences-between-collectors-tomap-and-collectors-groupingby-to-collect-in/45231743)

Answer (score 3):

Since your array rows always consist of a pair of numbers and you consider the first element as key and the second as value, it would be obvious at first glance if you map them to `SimpleEntry`:

```
int[][] prerequisites = { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 } };
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = 
            Arrays.stream(prerequisites)
                  .map(arr -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(arr[0], arr[1]))
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Exactly I think  also same at a first glance my first solution was exactly same.