# Java 11: convert List<String> to TreeMap<String, List<String>> using Collectors

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list like that

```
List<String> customList = Arrays.asList(
   "5000  Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease",
   "6000  characterized by the development",
   "7000  of painless open wounds.",
   "8000  The disease largely occurs in",
   "10000  sub-Saharan Africa and Australia."
);
```

I want to convert that `List` into a `TreeMap<String, List<String>>` like that:

```
"5000", ["Buruli", "ulcer", "is", "an", "infectious", "disease"]
"6000", ["characterized", "by", "the", "development"]
// etc
```

My code so far:

```
TreeMap<String, List<String[]>> collect = customList.stream()
      .map(s -> s.split("  ", 2))
      .collect(Collectors
         .groupingBy(a -> a[0], TreeMap::new, Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1].split(" "), Collectors.toList())));
```

I have two problems.

1. First is that `TreeMap::new` is probably not working because the order is not the same as the original's `List`.
2. Second is that I don't seem to find a way to make that `List<String[]>` into a `List<String>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `TreeMap` *sorts* entries by key. You want to use `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Exactly what ernest_k says. You don't want to sort here. You want to *preserve order*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve original order. So your code should look like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = customList.stream()
    .map(s -> s.split(" +"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> Arrays.asList(a)
        .subList(1, a.length), (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If your keys are not unique, you can use the grouping collector with something like this (`Collectors.flatMapping` requires Java 9+):

```
collect = customList.stream()
    .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" +")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0), 
        LinkedHashMap::new, 
        Collectors.flatMapping(l -> l.stream().skip(1), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: This yields the expected output.

Comment: Alternatively, if the original list could contain clashes, that `(a, b) -> a` could be a list merging function (don't foget that `Arrays.asList()` returns a non-extendable list).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I'm assuming the keys are unique. Otherwise, groupBy, as Arvind suggests, is the way to do it (or of course a proper merge function in toMap).

Comment: Note that with a merge function (the 3rd parameter `Collectors.toMap()` takes) you'd do the same. `Collectors.groupingBy()` actually moves merging downstream, i.e. the `toList()` collector would handle that.

Comment: I had almost the same in mind as this code. However, I would have preserved the `map(s -> s.split("  ", 2))`, and then as `valueMapper` function `a -> Arrays.asList(a[1].split(" "))` instead of `a -> Arrays.asList(a).subList(1, a.length)`. Now I am slightly curious about whether it would matter or not.

Comment: @MCEmperor I wanted to avoid calling `String.split()` more than once :)

Comment: @ernest_k That seems like an understandable reason, and it also implies that you think it *does* matter. ;-) I can imagine that, for large input strings, you indeed *don't* want to split twice.

Comment: Is it possible to show the answer using `groupingBy`? I am curious about how can I use `Arrays.asList(a).subList(1, a.length)` with `groupingBy` function

Comment: @ThanosM It gets a bit hard to read. Here's one solution: `Map<String, List<String>> collect = customList.stream()
  .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" +")))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.get(0), LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors
      .collectingAndThen(Collectors.mapping(l -> l.subList(1, l.size()), Collectors.toList()),
        l -> l.stream()
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))));`. It may be simplified a lot if you're using Java 11.

Answer (score 5):

### Yet another update:

This update is to fulfil the following requirement mentioned by the OP as a comment below the answer:

> I would like each word as a separate element in the List. With your
> solution, all the elements are in the same List entry. For example, I
> would like 10000=[sub-Saharan, Africa, and, Australia.]

In order to achieve this, you should not split the string of words.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> customList = Arrays.asList(
                   "5000  Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease",
                   "6000  characterized by the development",
                   "7000  of painless open wounds.",
                   "8000  The disease largely occurs in",
                   "10000  sub-Saharan Africa and Australia."
                );
        
        TreeMap<String, List<String>> collect = customList.stream().map(s -> s.split("  ", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
                        () -> new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)),
                        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
        
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{5000=[Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease], 6000=[characterized by the development], 7000=[of painless open wounds.], 8000=[The disease largely occurs in], 10000=[sub-Saharan Africa and Australia.]}
```

Or the one based on my original answer:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> customList = Arrays.asList(
                   "5000  Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease",
                   "6000  characterized by the development",
                   "7000  of painless open wounds.",
                   "8000  The disease largely occurs in",
                   "10000  sub-Saharan Africa and Australia."
                );

        Map<String, List<String>> collect = customList.stream().map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{10000=[sub-Saharan Africa and Australia.], 5000=[Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease], 6000=[characterized by the development], 7000=[of painless open wounds.], 8000=[The disease largely occurs in]}
```

### The solution suggested by [Aniket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852111/java-8-convert-liststring-to-treemapstring-liststring-using-collectors/66852233#comment118172090_66852111):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> customList = Arrays.asList(
                   "5000  Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease",
                   "6000  characterized by the development",
                   "7000  of painless open wounds.",
                   "8000  The disease largely occurs in",
                   "10000  sub-Saharan Africa and Australia."
                );
        
        TreeMap<String, List<String>> collect = customList.stream().map(s -> s.split("  ", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
                        () -> new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)),
                        Collectors.mapping(a -> Arrays.toString(a[1].split(" ")), Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{5000=[[Buruli, ulcer, is, an, infectious, disease]], 6000=[[characterized, by, the, development]], 7000=[[of, painless, open, wounds.]], 8000=[[The, disease, largely, occurs, in]], 10000=[[sub-Saharan, Africa, and, Australia.]]}
```

### Original answer:

You were almost there. You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> customList = Arrays.asList(
                   "5000  Buruli ulcer is an infectious disease",
                   "6000  characterized by the development",
                   "7000  of painless open wounds.",
                   "8000  The disease largely occurs in",
                   "10000  sub-Saharan Africa and Australia."
                );

        Map<Object, List<Object>> collect = customList.stream().map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(a -> Arrays.asList(a[1].split("\\s+")), Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{10000=[[sub-Saharan, Africa, and, Australia.]], 5000=[[Buruli, ulcer, is, an, infectious, disease]], 6000=[[characterized, by, the, development]], 7000=[[of, painless, open, wounds.]], 8000=[[The, disease, largely, occurs, in]]}
```

Comment: are there any advantages to using `groupBy` instead of `toMap` if knowing the keys are unique?

Comment: @ThanosM - There are many excellent answers already available describing the difference between these two e.g. you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45231351/10819573).

Comment: I would like each word as a separate element in the `List`. With your solution, all the elements are in the same `List` entry. For example, I would like `10000=[sub-Saharan, Africa, and, Australia.]`

Comment: @ThanosM - I was out for lunch. Just saw your comment and posted an update as the solution to this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.